# Download packages from repository and install local copy

Tags: software-installation

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD

1. To replace Network Manager with WICD,

   > First, we download the latest NetworkManager, in case we need to
   >   reinstall if WICD doesn't works:
   >
   > ```
   > sudo apt-get install -d --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome
   > ```
   >
   > Then we install WICD:
   >
   > ```
   > sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk
   > ```
   >
   > And only then do we uninstall NetworkManager:
   >
   > ```
   > sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager-gnome network-manager
   > ```

   In the first step, since it doesn't actually install Network Manager
   (`-d`), is `-reinstall` in the first step needed? Why?
2. When reverting to NetworkManager, does the following installation of
   Network  Manager need internet connection? I.e. is it from the
   previously downloaded package, or from the repository on the
   Internet? If I want to install from the local copy, which command
   shall I run?

   > Open up a Terminal and execute the following commands:
   >
   > ```
   > Install NetworkManager:
   >
   >     sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome network-manager 
   > Then remove WICD:
   >
   >     sudo apt-get remove --purge wicd wicd-gtk 
   > Finally, restart your system.
   > ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. The combination of `-d` and  `--reinstall` makes no sense:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install -d --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome

   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
   Need to get 0 B/1.087 kB of archives.
   After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
   Download complete and in download only mode
   ```

   You need only a

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -d network-manager network-manager-gnome
   ```
2. It's the local version, install with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ...`

   ```
   $ ping google.de

   ping: unknown host google.de

   $ sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager-gnome network-manager

   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
   Need to get 0 B/1.087 kB of archives.
   After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
   (Reading database ... 417744 files and directories currently installed.)
   Preparing to unpack .../network-manager_0.9.10.0-4ubuntu15.1_amd64.deb ...
   Unpacking network-manager (0.9.10.0-4ubuntu15.1) over (0.9.10.0-4ubuntu15.1) ...
   Preparing to unpack .../network-manager-gnome_0.9.10.1-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
   Unpacking network-manager-gnome (0.9.10.1-0ubuntu4) over (0.9.10.1-0ubuntu4) ...
   Processing triggers for dbus (1.8.12-1ubuntu5) ...
   Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
   Processing triggers for systemd (219-7ubuntu3) ...
   Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
   ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
   Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.44.0-1ubuntu3) ...
   No such key 'external-editor' in schema 'org.gnome.eog.ui' as specified in override file '/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/20_ubuntu-gnome-default-settings.gschema.override'; ignoring override for this key.
   Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.44.0-1ubuntu3) ...
   No such key 'external-editor' in schema 'org.gnome.eog.ui' as specified in override file '/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/20_ubuntu-gnome-default-settings.gschema.override'; ignoring override for this key.
   Processing triggers for gconf2 (3.2.6-3ubuntu1) ...
   Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.14-0ubuntu1) ...
   Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu5) ...
   Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
   Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
   Setting up network-manager (0.9.10.0-4ubuntu15.1) ...
   Setting up network-manager-gnome (0.9.10.1-0ubuntu4) ...
   ```